# Delete multidimensional hash in a loop

Tags: loops, perl, hash

I'm doing a hierarchical clustering and I need to remove the clustered elements before moving on to the next step. I did the code for a single-dimensional hash and it ran fine. Now I have a two-dimensional hash, I'm unable to delete the elements.

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
    'S1' => {
        'A1' => 10,
        'A2' => 11,
        'A3' => 5,
    },
    'S2' => {
        'A1' => 6,
        'A2' => 8,
        'A3' => 3,
    },
    'S3' => {
        'A1' => 20,
        'A2' => 21,
        'A3' => 15,
    },
    'S4' => {
        'A1' => 7,
        'A2' => 6,
        'A3' => 4,
    },
    'S5' => {
        'A1' => 3,
        'A2' => 2,
        'A3' => 10,
    },
);

my @array = ('A1', 'A2', 'A3');

my %distances;
for my $key_1 (sort keys %hash) {
    for my $key_2 (sort keys %hash) {
        if ($key_1 ne $key_2) {
            my $deviation_vectors;
            foreach (@array) {
                $deviation_vectors += ($hash{$key_1}{$_} - $hash{$key_2}{$_}) ** 2;
            };
            $distances{$key_1}{$key_2} = $deviation_vectors ** 0.5 unless $distances{$key_2}{$key_1};
        };
    };
};
my @values;
while (my ($key, $element) = each %distances) {
    while (my ($element, $value) = each %{$element}) {
        push @values, $value;
    };
};
my $min = (sort {$a <=> $b} @values)[0];
for my $key_1 (sort keys %hash) {
    for my $key_2 (sort keys %hash) {
        if ($key_1 ne $key_2) {
            my $deviation_vectors;
            foreach (@array) {
                $deviation_vectors += ($hash{$key_1}{$_} - $hash{$key_2}{$_}) ** 2;
            };
            if ($min == $deviation_vectors ** 0.5) {
                my $new_key = "$key_1,$key_2";
                foreach (@array) {
                    $hash{$new_key}{$_} = mean($hash{$key_1}{$_}, $hash{$key_2}{$_});
                };
# Problem here
# Delete doesn't completely remove the element, it returns a hash with an empty key element
                delete $hash{$key_1};
                delete $hash{$key_2};
            };
        };
    };
};
print Dumper \%hash;

sub mean {
    my @data = @_;
    my $sum;
    foreach (@data) {
        $sum += $_;
    };
    return ($sum / @data)
};
```

This is the result I got...

```
$VAR1 = {
          'S4' => {},
          'S2' => {},
          'S3' => {
                    'A1' => 20,
                    'A3' => 15,
                    'A2' => 21
                  },
          'S2,S4' => {
                       'A2' => 7,
                       'A1' => '6.5',
                       'A3' => '3.5'
                     },
          'S1' => {
                    'A3' => 5,
                    'A1' => 10,
                    'A2' => 11
                  },
          'S5' => {
                    'A3' => 10,
                    'A1' => 3,
                    'A2' => 2
                  }
        };
```

'S2' and 'S4' need to be completely removed from the hash.

Comment: Please add `use warnings;` to your code -- it will give you an idea what code line causes the problem. You recreate elements of the hash in loop when you attempt to access deleted element -- in Perl it named [autovivication](https://perlmaven.com/autovivification).

Comment: In your code you can use `my @keys = sort keys %hash` and reuse `@keys` more efficiently. You could use `$sum += $_ for @data;` to compute __mean__ -- the code would be more readable.

Comment: Thank you @PolarBear. Learning new things about Perl every day!

Comment: Also you use `**2` and `**0.5` -- perhaps you intended to use [abs](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/abs) instead in your code.

Comment: @PolarBear erm, actually it's different from abs. I sum all of the squared differences then square root that sum. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to delete keys? This feels like an XY-problem. Usually, you don't need to delete something if you just never look at it again. So why do you need to delete keys?

Comment: @TLP I'm writing a subroutine for agglomerative clustering from scratch. So following the algorithm, I have to remove the elements after I cluster them into a group.

Comment: @Tiendu But you are looping over a fixed list of the keys? So if you first check key S1 vs S2, then delete those keys, the next loop iteration will be to check S1 against S3, but now S1 does not exist. You don't check this at all, but perform the calculations anyway. Next check is S1 against S4, and so on. If you had use warnings turned on (which I assume you have off or you would know), you would get a ton of warnings about this. `Use of uninitialized value in subtraction (-) at ..`

Comment: @TLP I'm quite aware of this problem and it consumed a lot of RAM when I ran it on a real dataset. Right now, I've not thought of any better way to do it. I'll put the whole subroutine in the solution below. Thanks for pointing it out but I think I need more time to optimise the code.

Comment: With the above data, you would only be doing comparisons in pairs, S1 vs S2, S3 vs S4, and S5 would have nothing to compare to. In total 2 comparisons, then all the keys are deleted. Is that what you want?

Comment: @TLP erm no, it is a pairwise comparison of all the elements e.g., S1 vs S2, S1 vs S3, S1 vs S4,..., S3 vs S4, S3 vs S5 and S4 vs S5. Then if any of the pair in comparison has the least difference, it'll be replaced by a new element that has the value is the mean of the pair that has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Please inspect following code which is based on provided code with some *modification* to remove excessive loop cycles with introduction of two indexes.

Perhaps hash `%distances` in this algorithm is excessive, it is kept for demonstration purpose only as it can be useful to OP.

NOTE: the code is provided for an demonstration purpose in an attempt to improve code readability

INFO: `$distance ** 0.5` is better written as `sqrt($distance)`, documentation [sqrt](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sqrt)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
    'S1' => {
        'A1' => 10,
        'A2' => 11,
        'A3' => 5,
    },
    'S2' => {
        'A1' => 6,
        'A2' => 8,
        'A3' => 3,
    },
    'S3' => {
        'A1' => 20,
        'A2' => 21,
        'A3' => 15,
    },
    'S4' => {
        'A1' => 7,
        'A2' => 6,
        'A3' => 4,
    },
    'S5' => {
        'A1' => 3,
        'A2' => 2,
        'A3' => 10,
    },
);

my(%distances, $deviation, @array, @keys);

@array = qw(A1 A2 A3);
@keys  = sort keys %hash;

for my $index_1 (0..$#keys) {
    for my $index_2 (1+$index_1..$#keys) {
        my($distance, $key_1, $key_2) = (0, $keys[$index_1], $keys[$index_2]);
        
        $distance += ( $hash{$key_1}{$_} - $hash{$key_2}{$_} ) ** 2 for @array;
        $distance = $distance ** 0.5;

        $distances{$key_1}{$key_2} = $distance;

        $deviation->{min} = $distance unless $deviation->{min};
         
        if( $deviation->{min} > $distance ) {
            $deviation->{min} = $distance;
            $deviation->{keys} = [$key_1, $key_2];
        }
    }
}

my($key_1, $key_2) = $deviation->{keys}->@*;

$hash{"$key_1,$key_2"}{$_} = mean($hash{$key_1}{$_}, $hash{$key_2}{$_}) for @array;

delete @hash{($key_1, $key_2)};

say Dumper(\%hash);

exit 0;

sub mean {
    my @data = @_;
    my $sum;
    
    $sum += $_ for @data;
    
    return $sum / @data;
}
```

Output sample

```
$VAR1 = {
          'S2,S4' => {
                       'A1' => '6.5',
                       'A2' => '7',
                       'A3' => '3.5'
                     },
          'S5' => {
                    'A1' => 3,
                    'A3' => 10,
                    'A2' => 2
                  },
          'S3' => {
                    'A1' => 20,
                    'A3' => 15,
                    'A2' => 21
                  },
          'S1' => {
                    'A2' => 11,
                    'A3' => 5,
                    'A1' => 10
                  }
        };
```

Comment: Immense thanks! But may I ask you about the '@*'. I've seen it alot but still don't know what it does. I searched it up and it means multi lines.

Comment: It denotes that stored value is an __array__ reference type which this operation dereferences (`->` means reference, `@` an array). Book [Modern Perl](http://www.nylxs.com/docs/modern-perl-fourth-edition_p1_0.pdf) see page 71,  You also might find useful [Learn Perl](https://www.perl.org/) website, and [tutorials](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl#Tutorials). Perl [cheatsheet](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlcheat) can be useful as well to newcomers into Perl world.

Comment: @Tiendu `xxx->@*` is the same as `@{xxx}`. It's called "postfix dereferencing" (googling for that will have more success than googling for `@*` directly!).

Comment: You can lookup documentation for [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax) where there is a description what it does.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the subroutine I've made from @Polar Bear solution. It has three parameters, the first one will be the input data, the second one will be the array of sub-elements, then the last one will be the threshold where we want to stop the subroutine.

```
...
sub agglomerative_clustering {
    my %data = %{$_[0]};
    my @array = @{$_[1]};
    my $threshold = $_[2];
    my $size = keys %data;
    my %clusters;
    for (my $i = 1; $i < $size; $i++) {
        my (%distances, $find, @keys);
        @keys = sort keys %data;
        for my $index_1 (0 .. $#keys) {
            for my $index_2 (1 + $index_1 .. $#keys) {
                my ($distance, $key_1, $key_2) = (0, $keys[$index_1], $keys[$index_2]);
                $distance += ($data{$key_1}{$_} - $data{$key_2}{$_}) ** 2 foreach @array;
                $distance = sqrt($distance);
                $distances{$key_1}{$key_2} = $distance;
                $find->{min} = $distance unless $find->{min};
                $find->{key} = [$key_1, $key_2] unless $find->{key};
                if ($find->{min} > $distance) {
                    $find->{min} = $distance;
                    $find->{key} = [$key_1, $key_2];
                };
            };
        };
        my ($key_1, $key_2) = $find->{key}->@*;
        $data{"$key_1,$key_2"}{$_} = mean($data{$key_1}{$_}, $data{$key_2}{$_}) foreach @array;
        delete @data{($key_1, $key_2)};
        last if $find->{min} >= $threshold;
        %clusters = %data;
    };
    return %clusters;
};

sub mean {
    my @data = @_;
    my $sum;
    $sum += $_ for @data;    
    return $sum / @data;
};
...
```

Comment: Sufficient to write one line `delete @hash{@deleted}` -- please see doc for [delete](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete)